# Generating insert statements from an sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

Is there any tool or script available?

Comment: You need to be MUCH more descriptive if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
sqlite x.db .dump > output.sql
```

This will dump the SQL to regenerate a database

Comment: How to do that only for a specific table?

Answer (score 7):

[DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) supports SQL generation.

- Go to `File`
- Select `Export`
- Click to `Database to SQL file...`
- A popup screen will be shown.
- There you can choose export options and click `OK`
- It'll prompt for a location to save generated sql file.

I hope it'll help the others :)

Comment: This is similar to SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) Database - Tasks - Generate Scripts tool.

Comment: @apdevelop Yes, this is what I like about this tool :) No need for the fancy console commands :) I'm glad that you found it useful :)

Answer (score 5):

To generate output into a file follow these steps:

```
$ sqlite3 mytable.db

sqlite> .output output.sql

sqlite> .dump table_name

sqlite> .quit
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you use the [Sqlite manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) firefox plugin, it supports bulk inserts from `INSERT` SQL statements.</strike>

Infact it doesn't support this, but [Sqlite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) does (works on Windows, OS X, Linux)

Answer (score 1):

As a quick work around for fewer column tables. We can use string concatenation function. Sample example is- 
`select 'insert into TABLE_NAME values('''|| COLUMN1 || ''',''' || COLUMN2 || ''',''' || COLUMN3 || ''',''' || COLUMN4 || ''');'  from TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/

SQLite Administrator is a powerful tool if you easily want to create, design or administrate SQLite database files. The SQL code editor helps you to quickly write sql queries with features such as code completion and highlighting. Both major versions of SQLite database files are supported by SQLite Administrator.
Features:

```
* Create / Modify / Delete Tables by Wizard
* Create / Modify / Delete Indices by Wizard
* Create / Modify / Delete Views by Wizard
* Create / Modify / Delete Triggers by Wizard
* SQL Code Completion that supports table aliases
* SQL Code Highlighting
* SQL Error Locating
* Import Data from CSV Files
* Export Data ( XLS / CSV / HTML / XML )
* Store User Queries into Database
* Search for User Queries
* Store Images into Blob Fields ( JPG / BMP )
* Show SQL of each Database Item
* Migrate SQLite2 Databases to SQLite3
* Try to keep Indices and Triggers after modifying a Table
```

Comment: it dose't export to sql